# How to compare current_url with site_url in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have used something like that-

```
<?php if(current_url() == site_url()): ?>
```

...
...

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it's not working. I think there's something that I missed.

Comment: just echo the `current_url() ` and  `site_url()`

Comment: I have tried your method, but it shows syntax error. Something unexpected echo.

Comment: edit the config->autoload.php `$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');`

Comment: so.. whats the verdict?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to check if you're on the homepage of your site try this:

```
<?php if(strcmp(uri_string(),'')==0) : ?>

    We are on the home page.

<?php endif; ?>
```

This solution will still work regardless of whether the base url is set correctly or not, unlike comparing `base_url()` and `current_url()`.

Ensure that you have loaded the url helper either in your constructor or via autoloading.